# Missing cap on ceiling sprinkler

Tags: repair, ceiling, sprinkler-system, fire-sprinkler

I found this sprinkler head in the ceiling of my new place with a cover cap missing - later I found the cap in a drawer.

How would I go about replacing this? Is there a way to attach the original cap? Do I need to get a professional to take a look? I'm afraid of accidentally setting the sprinkler off.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: New place = signle-family home, or multiple unit occupancy (condo/apartment?) If the latter, fire suppression might be "building management's" turf anyway (ie, don't touch, contact them.) The metallic bit of the sprinkler cover appears to be a backing plate that is supposed to be installed in a precise hole and held by the projecting bumps, but it's a really crude hole you actually have. Precision is implied by the size of the bumps - alternatively, there might be some sort of spring clip that's missing or lost in the ceiling which has a precision fit and makes up for crude holes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in total agreement with Ecnerwal, that those bumps were to hold it in wall board. Finding this picture tells a different story: (notice the bumps and the threaded insert)

[image]

My best guess is that up in the ceiling somewhere, is the rest of the part; those bumps thread into it, or you can [just push (see, 4.a)](http://www.vikinggroupinc.com/databook/sprinklers/040600.pdf). Be gentle with it, those are [50 bucks](http://www.bulkindustries.com/Escutcheon-CENTRAL-Model-A-Royal-Flush-Concealed-F126.htm).

Again, I agree with E, don't touch it unless you own the building. Even then, you might want to call in whomever has the service contract for it.

Comment: I agree with @Mazura. On a side note, unless the pic is giving me a misunderstanding due to perspective, it seems the pendant deflector is flush with the ceiling which is an improper installation. I believe it needs to hang below the ceiling to properly distribute water spray during fire conditions. If this is indeed the case, you should bring it up to building management if / when you contact them.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, that would explain why the bumps aren't engaging. It does look high, but it'd have to be to use these; dunno. If I were brave, I'd pull another one down and make sure this one still works, in its place. Then you'd know if it's a $50 problem or a $500 problem.

Comment: Threads rather than spring-clip; good sleuthing, M.

Comment: @Mazura $500 is a very conservative estimate if they are going to have to pull down the ceiling and have a steamfitter come in and redo the sprinklers at the proper height.